# TableView data not loading

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase

For some reason, my data isn't loading into my tableview. The `fetchTasks` function seems to be working because if I add a breakpoint to it, it tells me that `tasks` has 151 Tasks in it but when I try and print tasks from anywhere outside of the `fetchTasks` function, it tells me that tasks is an empty array. I would assume that this is why my `updateTableView` function isn't working. When I print each of those variables it also gives me an empty array. I'm not getting any errors in Xcode so its a bit frustrating that I can't get this to work. Any help would be great. I've done a ton of googling already. Thanks in advance.

```
class TasksTVC: UITableViewController, TaskCellDelegate {


    let ref = Firebase(url: URL)
    var cell = TaskCell()
    var team = ""
    var sectionTimes = [String]()
    var tasksInSectionArray = [[Task]]()
    var tasks = [Task]() {
        didSet {
            tableView?.reloadData()
        }
    }

    func fetchTasks() {
        let tasksRef = Firebase(url: "\(self.ref)/tasks")
        tasksRef.queryOrderedByChild("team").queryEqualToValue(team).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
            var newTasks = [Task]()
            for task in snapshot.children {
                let tasks = Task(snapshot: task as! FDataSnapshot)
                newTasks.append(tasks)
            }
            self.tasks = newTasks
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        fetchTasks()
        }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        updateTableView()
        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
    }

    func updateTableView() {
        sectionTimes = Set(tasks.map{$0.dueTime}).sort()
        tasksInSectionArray = sectionTimes.map{section in tasks.filter{$0.dueTime == section}}
        print("section times:\(sectionTimes)")
        print(tasksInSectionArray)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }


    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return sectionTimes[section]
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sectionTimes.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tasksInSectionArray[section].count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TaskCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TaskCell

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.selectionStyle = .None
        let task = tasksInSectionArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        cell.label.text = task.title
        if task.done == true {
            cell.checkBox.image = UIImage(named: "checkedbox")
            cell.detailLabel.text = "Completed By: \(task.completedBy)"
            }
            else {
            cell.checkBox.image = UIImage(named: "uncheckedbox")
            cell.detailLabel.text = ""
            }

        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }


}
```

Comment: What if you use dispatch_async to put reloadData onto the main queue?

Comment: Which reloadData? Updatetableview()?

Comment: Sorry...I meant inside the block you send to the query.

Comment: no luck with that solution. what were you thinking that would do?

Comment: Where is the variable 'team' set? tasksRef.queryOrderedByChild("team").queryEqualToValue(**team**).  It's initialized to "" to start with but I don't see any code that makes anything other than an empty string.

Comment: you should call updateTableView in didSet of 'var tasks' and remove it from fetchTasks

Comment: team comes from the previous view. its brought over with a prepareForSegue method.

Comment: remove what from fetchTasks?

Comment: Ali AB, you were correct. You should submit that as an answer and I'll choose it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are never calling `updateTableView` after you fetch your tasks. That is the method that is organizing the data correctly for the table view.

Comment: I called it in viewDidLoad. I'm still new to Swift. Where else would I call it?

Comment: You need to call it again `after` you have all your data.